# Passing a Solr search query to a view

Tags: views, 6, search

When a user enters a search query into an Apache Solr Search box, is it possible to pass that query onto a view - specifically to a Apache Solr Views view?

Answer (score 2):

While you could technically do this by implementing a `hook_form_alter`, to capture and overwrite the submit handler, if you're already using the Apache Solr Views module, you'd be better off creating an exposed filter, setting the exposed filters to display in a block, and then using that instead of the default search form block. You can do that without custom code.

Comment: Well I want to use apachesolr_autocomplete.  It produces messy results when you integrate apachesolr_autocomplete into the views3 search filter.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use [Search API](http://drupal.org/project/search_api) with [Solr](http://drupal.org/project/search_api_solr) support as it has better integration with Views and [Drupal Recruter distribution](http://drupal.org/project/recruiter) is using exactly the same approach as you described.
It has support for [autocomplete](http://drupal.org/project/search_api_autocomplete), [spell checker](http://drupal.org/project/search_api_spellcheck) etc. as well.

So by creating exposed block in solr View, you're able to pass the query onto a view.